# MySQL select the largest value along with greater-than clause?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

How to select only **one row** that has **highest** value in `colum1`, also making sure that the selected `colum1` value is **greater-than** n

```
SELECT * FROM thetable WHERE colum1 >= 150 ORDER BY amount LIMIT 1
//using limit to get 1 row
//using where to fulfill greathe-than criteria
//using order by to sort and get max one.
```

The above query is giving greater-than 150 row but not the maximum one of table, what is wrong in query?

Comment: You'd need `ORDER BY amount  DESC`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `max` and `having` like this hypothetical query. Here we are getting the country with the highest number of branches which has more than 7 branches (8 or more):

```
SELECT country,MAX(no_of_branch)
FROM publisher
GROUP BY country
HAVING MAX(no_of_branch)>=8;
```

More [here](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-max-with-having.php)